# Circular Permutations With Repetitions (Mirrored Ignored)

Tags: permutations

For Circular Permutations with unique elements (mirrored ignored) the answer is (n - 1)!/2 (pretty straight forward). However I cant seem to figure out how to calculate circular permutations with repetitions allowed. So the Question is: Given 'm' elements, how many circular permutations (size 'n') with repetitions (mirrored ignored) are there?

Comment: What do you mean by 'mirror ignored'.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what you seek: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_%28combinatorics%29

Now, please ask next question over at math.stackexchange instead, if it is not research level.